# Monitor all ressources use?

Tags: arch-linux, monitoring

Is there a program to monitor all ressource utilzation at once for a personal computer : CPU, memory, hard drives ?

Comment: Locally or also using external services?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio locally just for my personal computer

Comment: Using top command for CPU and Memory.Using df -h command for harddisk.To monitor all using Nagios monitor tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [Conky](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky). Also searching for CPU widgets for ArchLinux will give you a lot of results for what you want.

Additionally, if you want to know all that information via CLI, you can have it quickly with:

```
echo CPU: && mpstat && echo && echo MEMORY: && free && echo && echo "DISK USAGE:" && df -h
```